# i want my popup window to appear in center

Tags: scala

i had created my popup window which is appearing on a click of link but it is coming at the top corner  of window and want it to appear it in at center and also want to resize it. i had created it in scala and calling it with html file.so everybody please give your suggetions as fast as possible.

Comment: I think what you need is to learn basic HTML/CSS first.

Comment: "as fast as possible". I'll put it down to a poor grasp of English but it's not the ideal way to get help

Comment: He made the same request with his last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947981/want-to-create-a-popup-in-scala

Answer (score 5):

This question is just so wrong, web pages aren't written in Scala; they're written in HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

*Please, please* stop taking some very fundamental questions about basic web design / jQuery concepts and tagging them as Scala.  *You do not have a **Scala** problem.*

My advice to you is to **forget Scala**, at least for now.  Concentrate on just writing static web pages using JavaScript/jQuery.  Once you have a level of understanding there, start looking at Scala, but not for web pages, just get a feel for the language by writing command-line tools.

Then, and only then, you can start learning the Lift framework, and tie it all together.

Alternatively, you could always try Ruby on Rails, it's supposed to be easier to learn than Lift.

Also, you really should post samples of any code you're struggling with, it makes it far easier for others to spot the problem if they can see the code.